# Creating a clicking counter on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, click, game-physics

I created a little game with JavaScript while i am learning it.
I would like to get a count clicker in it. So you can see how many times you have clicked on the canvas before you die. (so it resets right after the 'game over'.

Here is the JS code i have at the moment:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {

  //constants
  var GAME_WIDTH = 640;
  var GAME_HEIGHT = 360;

  //keep the game going
  var gameLive = true;

  //current level
  var level = 1;



  //enemies
  var enemies = [{
      x: 100, //x coordinate
      y: 100, //y coordinate
      speedY: 2, //speed in Y
      w: 40, //width
      h: 40 //heght
    },
    {
      x: 200,
      y: 0,
      speedY: 2,
      w: 40,
      h: 40
    },
    {
      x: 330,
      y: 100,
      speedY: 3,
      w: 40,
      h: 40
    },
    {
      x: 450,
      y: 100,
      speedY: -3,
      w: 40,
      h: 40
    }
  ];

  //the player object
  var player = {
    x: 10,
    y: 160,
    speedX: 2.5,
    isMoving: false, //keep track whether the player is moving or not
    w: 40,
    h: 40
  };

  //the goal object
  var goal = {
    x: 580,
    y: 160,
    w: 50,
    h: 36
  }
  // var zonder waarde
  var img = {};

  var movePlayer = function () {
    player.isMoving = true;
  }

  var stopPlayer = function () {
    player.isMoving = false;
  }


  //grab the canvas and context
  var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  //event listeners to move player
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', movePlayer);
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', stopPlayer);
  canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', movePlayer);
  canvas.addEventListener('touchend', stopPlayer);

  var load = function () {
    img.player = new Image();
    img.player.src = 'images/ping.png';

    img.background = new Image();
    img.background.src = 'images/sea.png';

    img.enemy = new Image();
    img.enemy.src = 'images/enemy.png';

    img.goal = new Image();
    img.goal.src = 'images/fish.png';
  };

  //update the logic
  var update = function () {



    //check if you've won the game
    if (checkCollision(player, goal)) {

      // leven +1
      level++;
      // level in console 
      console.log(level);

      // get player back in position
      player.x = 10;
      player.y = 160;
      //increase the speed of the enemies by 1

      //increase the speed of the enemies by 1
      enemies.forEach(function (enemies) {
        if (enemies.speedY > 0) {
          enemies.speedY++;
        } else {
          enemies.speedY--;
        }
      });

    }

    //update player
    if (player.isMoving) {
      player.x = player.x + player.speedX;
    }


    enemies.forEach(function (element, index) {

      //check for collision with player
      if (checkCollision(player, element)) {
        //stop the game
        gameLive = false;

        alert('Game Over!');

        //reload page
        window.location = "";
      };

      //move enemy
      element.y += element.speedY;

      //check borders
      if (element.y <= 10) {
        element.y = 10;
        //element.speedY = element.speedY * -1;
        element.speedY *= -1;
      } else if (element.y >= GAME_HEIGHT - 50) {
        element.y = GAME_HEIGHT - 50;
        element.speedY *= -1;
      }

    });
  };

  //show the game on the screen
  var draw = function () {

    //clear the canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);

    //draw background
    ctx.drawImage(img.background, 0, 0);

    //draw player
    ctx.drawImage(img.player, player.x, player.y);

    //draw enemies
    enemies.forEach(function (element, index) {
      ctx.drawImage(img.enemy, element.x, element.y);
    });

    //draw goal
    ctx.drawImage(img.goal, goal.x, goal.y);

    //for seeing the level in canvas

    //color points
    ctx.fillStyle = "#339900";
    //font points
    ctx.font = "60px Michroma";
    //point shower
    ctx.fillText(level, 10, 55);

  };

  //gets executed multiple times per second
  var step = function () {

    update();
    draw();

    if (gameLive) {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
    }
  };

  //check the collision between two rectangles
  var checkCollision = function (rect1, rect2) {

    var closeOnWidth = Math.abs(rect1.x - rect2.x) <= Math.max(rect1.w, rect2.w);
    var closeOnHeight = Math.abs(rect1.y - rect2.y) <= Math.max(rect1.h, rect2.h);
    return closeOnWidth && closeOnHeight;

  }

  //initial kick
  load();
  step();
});
```

I tried some things out of hand but i couldn't figure it out. Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Kind regards

Comment: Why is this tagged with `css`?  Question is entirely about javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new variable to increment then within the movePlayer function increment this value. When the game is over you can reset the variable to 0.

For example, below the current level variable add `var clickCount = 0`;

Then within the movePlayer function add `clickCount += 1;`

As you are currently reloading the page once the game ends the variable will be reset.

This variable could be output in a simple DIV on the page and does not have to be part of the canvas.

It would be best if you had a working example with the images too. You could do this on https://codesandbox.io/ or https://codepen.io/

## UPDATE

Add a DOM element `<div id="clickCount">0</div>` onto your page. Then replace the movePlayer with the below.

```
var movePlayer = function () {
  clickCount += 1;
  player.isMoving = true;
  document.getElementById('clickCount').innerHTML = clickCount;
}
```

This will then update the DIV with the new count, you can then use CSS to position and style the DIV as you want.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer! So i added the var and i addd the clickCount. I am not sure what do do now?

Comment: Thanks for the update! This is what i was looking for! Thanks! :)